# Segmentation fault (core dumped) - dont know why

Tags: c++

I am on my way to learn C++. Im now trying to link a Library on Runtime. Im getting a segmentation fault error. I dont know why it happens.
Here is the cpp file where the error happens:

```
#include "CreateShape.h"

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "Shape.h"

namespace six
{
typedef six::Shape* (*GET_OBJECT);
Shape* create_shape(const char* name)
{
    Shape* shape = nullptr;
    std::stringstream libName;
    libName << "./lib" << name << ".so";
    void* handle = dlopen(libName.str().c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
    if(handle == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open the library" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "dlerror: "<< std::endl << dlerror() << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    GET_OBJECT createShape = reinterpret_cast<GET_OBJECT>(dlsym(handle, "getNewShape"));
    if(createShape == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not find symbol getNewShape" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "dlerror=" << dlerror() << std::endl;
        dlclose(handle);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return create_shape(name);
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In order to help you a [mcve] would be very nice.

Comment: When you step through the code in your debugger, after which line does the segmentation fault happen?

Comment: While I agree on providing a minimal reproducible example, isn't this function basically looping forever until either handle or createShape are nullptr, thus failing?

Comment: bnnein is right... what is this function? Why is it calling itself recursively? What is the purpose what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: btw as a beginner in c++ it would take me months to get this stuff right. pointers, loading dll, reinterpret_cast (?!), uff.. perhaps start with something simpler

Answer (score 2):

A stripped down version of your function is

```
Shape* create_shape(const char* name)
{
    if(some_condition)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(some_other_condition)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return create_shape(name);
}
```

Probably you wanted to return `shape` or some `Shape` that you created inside that function. What you do instead is calling the function recursively. The only way to stop recursion is when you hit one of the conditions and then call `exit`.

Though, i have to admit, why the symptom is a segfault I do not really understand.

Comment: can't a stack overflow on recursive calls generate a SIGSEGV?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the dl-calls the proper way. From the [linux dlopen(3) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen)

> dlsym()
>
> [...]Since the value of the symbol could actually be NULL (so that a NULL return from `dlsym()` need not indicate an error), the correct way to test for an error is to call `dlerror()` to clear any old error conditions, then call `dlsym()`, and then call `dlerror()` again, saving its return value into a variable, and check whether this saved value is not NULL.

Comment: That's very true, and might be relevant on some exotic platform, but doesn't answer the question.